# Why do I don't get any errors from Thread block?

Tags: ruby

I am running a rails 4 application and I have an code line in a module under libs which raises some kind of exception, but this is not show in the rails console neither in the dev console? So I found the mentioned code line by luck? Why is there no exception and stacktrace? Or how can I find the source of error?

For instance I have to following

```
 Thread.new {
  @rates.each do |rate|

    rate.save_rate unless rate.total.nil? or rate.total.empty
  end
}
```

rate.total is a fixnum and I get an error since empty? is not possible on fixnum. Might it be related to Thread?

Comment: Please provide sample code.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Also, see the comment by @zetetic.

If this is all your code - the reason for this is that you invoke a new thread, and don't wait for it to finish. That means, ruby interpreter fires a thread and when the script ends, it immediately exits, so nothing that's inside Thread block have a chance to be executed.

Try running this script from a terminal:

```
Thread.new do
  raise "won't see me"
end
```

It is almost certain that you won't see anything happen.

Now let's wait for the thread to be finished (by using `join`).

```
Thread.new do
  raise "won't see me"
end.join
```

If I run `$ ruby t.rb` I can finally see an error in stdout:

```
  t.rb:2:in `block in <main>': won't see me (RuntimeError)
```

And if my add something - I don't recommend using Threads unless you really know, what you're doing.

Comment: This is almost right, but the thread may also terminate before the main program without producing any output, because exceptions that occur in a thread cause it to die silently, unless `Thread.abort_on_exception` is changed from `false` (the default) to `true`.

Comment: Thank you @zetetic, I wasn't aware of the `abort_on_exception` option.